# Smaller text in subtitle screws up centering in lilypond

Tags: lilypond

I want the subtitle to be small and italic. I started by trying to add the italics, which worked. But when I added the `\small` tag it made the centering wrong:

[image]

```
    \header {
    title = "The People That in Darkness Sat"
    subtitle = \markup {\italic \small "The people that walked in darkness have seen a great light . . . Isa. 9:2"}
    }
```

I feel like its calculating the size of the text to center it before it applies the small tag. Not sure what to do.

Full code:

```
\paper{
left-margin = #3
right-margin = #3
print-page-number = ##t
}
\header {
title = "The People That in Darkness Sat"
subtitle = \markup {\italic \small "The people that walked in darkness have seen a great light . . . Isa. 9:2"}
}
end =
  #(define-music-function
    (parser location signature)
    (fraction?)
  #{
    \once \omit Staff.TimeSignature \time #signature
  #})
musicOne =   \relative c' {
\voiceOne \partial 4 \breathe d8 e |
g4 g g8 [a] b g |
e4 e e8 [d] c d |
e4 g \breathe b8 [a] g b |
a2. \bar "." \break g8 a |
d4 d d e8 d |
b4 b b8 [a] g a |
b4 a8 g \breathe d4 fis4 |

\end 3/4 g2. \bar ".."
  }
musicTwo =  \relative c' {
\voiceTwo
\partial 4 \breathe d8 c |
d4 d e d |
c b a b8 d |
b4 d c c |
d2. d4 |
d8 e fis4 g fis |
g fis e e |
fis e d d |
\end 3/4 d2. \bar ".."
}

musicThree =  \relative c' {
\voiceThree

\partial 4 \breathe b8 c |
b4 b b g |
g g a g |
g g e a |
fis2. b4 |
b c b a |
d d e b |
d c b a |
\end 3/4 b2. \bar ".."
}

musicFour =  \relative c' {
\voiceFour

\partial 4 \breathe g4 |
g4 fis e b |
c e fis g |
e b a a |
d2. g4 |
b a g fis |
g d c e |
b c d d |
\end 3/4 g,2. \bar ".."
}


verseOne = \lyricmode {\set stanza = "1."The _ peo -- ple that _ in _ dark -- ness sat _ A _ glo -- rious Light _ have _ seen. The _ Light has shined on _ them who long _ In _ shades of _ night have been.}
verseTwo = \lyricmode {\set stanza = "2."To _ hail Thee Sun _ of _ Right -- eous -- ness _ The _ gath -- ering na - tions _ come; They _ joy as when the _ reap -- ers bear _ Their _ har -- vest _ treas -- ures home.}
verseThree = \lyricmode {\set stanza = "3."For _ un -- to us _ a _ Child is born, _ To _ us a Son _ is _ given, And _ on His Shoul -- ders _ ev -- er rest _ All _ power in _ earth and heaven.}
verseFour = \lyricmode {\set stanza = "4."His _ name shall be _ the _ Prince of Peace, _ For_- _ ev -- er -- more _ a - dored,  The _ Won -- der -- ful the _ Coun -- sel -- lor, _ The _ great and _ might -- y Lord.  }
verseFive = \lyricmode {\set stanza = "5."His _ right -- eous gov - ern -ment _  and power _ Shall _ o -- ver all _ ex - tend; On _ judg -- ment and on _ jus -- tice based _ His _ reign shall _ have no end.}
verseSix = \lyricmode {\set stanza = "6."Lord _ Je -- sus, reign _ in _ us, we pray, _ And _ make us Thine _ a - lone, Who _ with the Fa -- ther _ ev -- er art, _ And _ Ho -- ly _ Spir -- it, one. }
\score {
    <<
    \new Staff  <<
    \new Voice = "one" {
      \time 4/4
      \numericTimeSignature
      \key g \major
      \musicOne
    }
      \new Voice = "two" {
      \time 4/4
      \numericTimeSignature
      \key g \major
      \musicTwo
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
      \verseOne
    }
        \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
      \verseTwo
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
      \verseThree
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
      \verseFour
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
      \verseFive
    }
    \new Lyrics \lyricsto "one" {
      \verseSix
    }
    >>
    \new Staff  <<
    \new Voice = "three" {
      \time 4/4
      \numericTimeSignature
      \key g \major
      \clef "bass"
      \musicThree
    }
     \new Voice = "four" {
      \time 4/4
      \numericTimeSignature
      \key g \major
      \clef "bass"
      \musicFour
    }
    >>
  >>

  \layout {
  indent = #0
  ragged-right = ##f
  ragged-last = ##f

  }
  \midi {}
}
```

Comment: Could you put the smaller text in a separate caption and centre it separately?

Comment: @ElementsinSpace I've added all my code to the main post. I'm using LilyPond 2.22.1 via the website Hacklily.

Comment: For me, compiling your code on hacklily results in fine output.

Comment: @ABOUSAMRAJean Interesting. For me, in the preview window it looks small, but not centered correctly. But when I export as a pdf, the text isn't small like its supposed to be, but the text is centered.. Perhaps a bug, I will download a program and see if I get different output.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't realise before but the exported PDF doesn't have small text for me either.

If I use the web browsers Chrome or Opera: I get the miss-centring bug. But if I use Safari it does center correctly, but `\small` does nothing on either the web page or the PDF. Hacklily is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your full code complies fine with the offline complier that I use — without any errors (only a warning that the version statement is missing).

---

Nevertheless, I am able to reproduce that bug with a much simpler code:

```
\version "2.22.1"

\header {
    title = "TITLE"
    subtitle = \markup { \italic "Subtitle subtitle" }
}

\score {
    {
        c'1 |
    }
}
```

... but *only* when using [Hacklily](https://www.hacklily.org/).

The bug seems to be with how the Hacklily page is handling `\italic` in the header block.
I don't understand why this is happening.

---

You can however, simply export from the Hacklily page GUI (`File -> Export -> PDF`), which will download a pdf that doesn't exhibit the bug.

Comment: I don't see the `\small` tag, did it not work or did you just leave it out by accident?

Comment: @Evan I took it out because I didn't think it was related to the problem.

Comment: Ah, you are right. Not sure how I got confused. I did have to use `\tiny` to get it as small as the bad scan I am upgrading. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This sounds like a bug you should report at Hacklily. I cannot reproduce it, BTW.

Comment: Actually, I can reproduce on Chrome, but not on Firefox.